# Java Plug-in Crashed in Firefox 28.0 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: firefox, java, plugins, javascript, add-on

I just installed Oracle Java 1.8.0_51 .And set as it as by default.I also linked libnpjp2.so file in Mozilla folder in /usr/lib/mozilla/plug-in. But when I am going to verify java its show no java plug-in in firefox's Addons.

But when i just copy libnpjp2.so file in the same directory it shows java in add-ons but while verifying its show java crashed error.

I am using following commands to set java defaults.

`JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_51
JRE_HOME=$JAVA_HOME/jre
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export JAVA_HOME
export JRE_HOME
export PATH`

`sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_51/bin/java" 1
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_51/bin/javac" 1
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javaws" "javaws" "/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_51/bin/javaws" 1`

`sudo update-alternatives --set java /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_51/bin/java
sudo update-alternatives --set javac /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_51/bin/javac
sudo update-alternatives --set javaws /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_51/bin/javaws`

   Its installed in system & shows

> root@hetd:/home/arjun# java -version
>
> Java version "1.8.0_51"
>   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_51-b16)
>   Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 25.51-b03, mixed mode)

Answer (score 1):

I just removed my old pre-installed mozilla firefox and installed new version of firefox .deb file in my computer .& again plug-in a soft link to mozilla plugin directory